# Cordova local storage doesn't clear when new app is installed

Tags: cordova, vue.js

I am currently working on a Vue.js/Cordova app and i'm using VueX-persist to save the store in local storage.

Within the store, I keep track of the current app version which I show on the login page of the app. My issue seems to be different on iOS and Android but both have the same issue where the storage doesn't clear when I re-install the app.

For example, I installed the app with version 1.0.7, then I changed the version to 1.0.8 and added some hard coded text so I knew this was installing the updated app.

Store.js:

```
state: {
    appVersion: '1.0.8', 
}
```

Login.vue:

```
<p>Should be version - 1.0.8 / Store Version is - {{$store.getters.appVersion}}</p>
```

The new app installs with the hard coded text, but the version still says 1.0.7 and this happens on iOS and Android.

The difference between the two come when I uninstall the app and try re-installing it.
On iOS, everything is updated correctly and works. Where as on android, even uninstalling the app causes no update to it. I have to clear the local storage manually and refresh the app for the change to take place. But even weirder is that once I delete the app and try `'cordova run android'` again, it goes back to 1.0.0 which was one of the first versions I made.

I have tried removing the platforms and re-adding them, re-running the following

```
npm run build 
cordova run ios
cordova run android
```

Update:

I updated the version again to 1.0.10, and run this code to check the version in the store and the version saved in local storage but both were reporting 1.0.9 (the old stored version)

```
// Function to migrate store data to keep it up dated after app updates
const migrateStoreData = function () {
  const previousStoreData = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('appStore'));
  console.log('Previous: ', previousStoreData.appVersion);
  console.log('Current: ', store.getters.appVersion);
};
migrateStoreData();
```

Comment: You can use a static json file instead, you can't  garantee the localStorage gonna be persited, if your device for some reasons has crital space localStorage can be arbitrary cleared. Use something to persists in a SQLite database, dont trust localStorage.

Answer (score 1):

This is a default behavior and i think it is okay like that.
Otherwise the users must login after each App update.

But of course there are situations where you have to migrate your stored data.

Thats why i run a migrations in main.js which just compares both versions (the currentAppVersion and the storedAppVersion)

If you want to delete all content from localStorage you must go to
`Settings->Apps` search your App and there klick on storage.
Now you have 2 Buttons to delete everything.

Hope that helps you

Comment: yeah this does seem logical to be honest when you think of it from that way - so perhaps I can run a function in main.js that checks if the version is altered and if so, it will clear the local storage and then copy over the user token etc to keep them logged in but everything else is updated?

Comment: I just tried this, added code to my question but it gave me the same app version both in local storage and the store ... unless it gets mutated before I run my function?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to use a reducer for Vuex Persist to exclude the 'appVersion' value from the store.

```
 const vuexPersist = new VuexPersist({
  key: 'appStore',
  storage: localStorage,
  reducer: state => // exclude certain values from being persisted
    Object.keys(state).reduce((acc, curr) => {
      if (!['appVersion'].includes(curr)) acc[curr] = state[curr];
      return acc;
    }, {}),
});
```